# I can't display a texture on a quad

Tags: opengl, freeimage

I am trying to wrap a texture on a quad.
All I see is a white rectangle:

[image]

To load the texture I used freeimage.

I need help in order to fix this very simple demo:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <FreeImage.h>
#include <stdio.h>

GLfloat coordinates[] =
{
    -0.5, 0.5, 1,
    -0.5, -0.5, 0,
    0.5, -0.5, 0,
    0.5, 0.5, 0
};

GLfloat texCoords[] =
{
    0, 1,
    0, 0,
    1, 0,
    1, 1
};

BYTE* data;

FIBITMAP* bitmap;
GLuint texture;

void initGlutCallbacks();
void initGL();
void onReshape(int w, int h);
void display();
FIBITMAP* loadTexture(const char* fileName);

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutInitWindowPosition(64, 64);
    glutCreateWindow("arrays");

    initGlutCallbacks();
    initGL();

    // texture
    bitmap = loadTexture("rufol.png");

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    data = FreeImage_GetBits(bitmap);
    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0,
        GL_RGBA8, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        data
    );

    // enable arrays
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // specifying data for the arrays
    glVertexPointer
    (
        3, GL_FLOAT, 0, coordinates
    );

    glTexCoordPointer
    (
        2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords
    );


    glutMainLoop();

}

void initGlutCallbacks(){
    glutReshapeFunc(onReshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
}

void initGL(){

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClearDepth(1.0);

    glEnable ( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

}

void onReshape(int w, int h){

}

void display(){

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();


}

FIBITMAP* loadTexture(const char* fileName){

    FIBITMAP *bitmap = FreeImage_Load(FIF_PNG, "rufol.png");
    if(bitmap == 0) printf("error loading the image\n");
    FIBITMAP *fbitmap = FreeImage_ConvertTo32Bits(bitmap);
    FreeImage_Unload(bitmap);
    return fbitmap;

}
```

As you can see I am not even using perspective. Also lighting is not enabled(I don't know if it is required to display textures). I have tested a very similar code but using colors for each vertex instead of texture coordinates and it worked. So I think it might be something wrong when loading the image.

Comment: call glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); before glDrawArrays and check FIBITMAP *bitmap = FreeImage_Load(FIF_PNG, "rufol.png"); returns null or not.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code. I introduced a printf for checking if bitmap is null. Nothing is printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using GL_RGBA instead of GL_RGBA8 as second parameter (format)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried but nothing happens.

Comment: You also have to bind texture right after glGenTextures

Comment: Another thing: are you sure FIBITMAP* contains raw pixel data? Shouldn't you use something like FreeImage_GetBits(bitmap)?

Comment: I think you are right, @mar. It seems there is still something to be solved. I will update the code of the question.

Comment: And you can omit glFlush, swapping buffers will take care of it

Comment: Changed RGBA to RGBA8 and ... now it works! Thank you very much! btw, could you explain the difference between RGBA and RGBA8 and why it didn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63633/discussion-between-user1754322-and-mar).

Comment: RGBA8 is valid internal format but not supplied data format, see https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml. Using RGBA as internal format (or simply 4) should work as well though.